# SQL statement that returns sums of records and returns both make names in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm a big confused on this one. I'm trying to use a SQL statement that sums up two different records but displays both 'Makes' of each row. I currently have this statement..

```
 SELECT  
     tDealerships.CapShortName,
     SUM(tObjective.CommitObj) AS CommitObj, 
     SUM(tObjective.ActualMTD) AS MTD, 
     SUM(tObjective.DelToday) AS DelT,
     SUM(tObjective.ActualMTD)/Sum(tObjective.CommitObj) AS CommitUnit,
     SUM(tObjective.CommitGrossObj) AS CommitGrossObj, 
     SUM(tObjective.GrossActual) AS GrossActual,
     SUM(tObjective.GrossActual)/Sum(tObjective.CommitGrossObj) as CommitGross,
     Sum(tObjective.ActualMTD)/Sum(tObjective.GrossActual) AS MTDPRU 
 FROM 
     tObjective, tMake, tDealerships
 WHERE 
     tObjective.DealershipID = 10
     AND NewUsed = 'New'
     AND tObjective.MakeID = tMake.MakeID
     AND tObjective.DealershipID = tDealerships.DealershipID
     AND (tMake.Make LIKE '%BUICK%' OR tMake.Make LIKE '%GMC%')
 GROUP BY 
     tDealerships.CapShortName
```

which returns this..

[image]

However, I need to display the two makes that it is summing up which is Buick and GMC. 
If I add the make in the statement, I must group by the make which then separates them into two row sums.. one for Buick and then one for GMC. Is there a better way or doing this? I am able to make it do what I need it to do? I have been stuck on this one for a bit now. Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The ideal result is having 1 result with an additional column named Make that displays both Buick/GMC together.

Comment: So it is summing both into `Shelbyville`, and you want shelbyville to come up twice splitting on Make?

Comment: Ok, you are showing us your current result, but what result do you want?, seems to me like 2 rows would be what you were after, but you say that you're not.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit strange. So I want the current result that is shown above, but another column that has Buick/GMC for the Make Column. Does that make sense?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had to hard-code the makes for the LIKE strings. Why not just hard code them in a literal for the make column?

```
 SELECT  
    tDealerships.CapShortName,
    SUM(tObjective.CommitObj) AS CommitObj, 
    SUM(tObjective.ActualMTD) AS MTD, 
    SUM(tObjective.DelToday) AS DelT,
    SUM(tObjective.ActualMTD)/Sum(tObjective.CommitObj) AS CommitUnit,
    SUM(tObjective.CommitGrossObj) AS CommitGrossObj, 
    SUM(tObjective.GrossActual) AS GrossActual,
    SUM(tObjective.GrossActual)/Sum(tObjective.CommitGrossObj) as CommitGross,
    Sum(tObjective.ActualMTD)/Sum(tObjective.GrossActual) AS MTDPRU 
    ------
    'GMC/Buick' As Make
    ------
 FROM tObjective, tMake, tDealerships
 WHERE tObjective.DealershipID = 10
    AND NewUsed = 'New'
    AND tObjective.MakeID = tMake.MakeID
    AND tObjective.DealershipID = tDealerships.DealershipID
    AND (tMake.Make LIKE '%BUICK%'
         OR tMake.Make LIKE '%GMC%')
 GROUP BY tDealerships.CapShortName
```

Comment: Holy crap that was an easy fix. I'm a moron. That will do perfectly!

Comment: I'm disappointed I didn't think of that. Simple solution, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something as simple as grouping on the make as well would solve your problem, if I am reading it correctly?

```
SELECT  
 tDealerships.CapShortName,
 SUM(tObjective.CommitObj) AS CommitObj, 
 SUM(tObjective.ActualMTD) AS MTD, 
 SUM(tObjective.DelToday) AS DelT,
 SUM(tObjective.ActualMTD)/Sum(tObjective.CommitObj) AS CommitUnit,
 SUM(tObjective.CommitGrossObj) AS CommitGrossObj, 
 SUM(tObjective.GrossActual) AS GrossActual,
 SUM(tObjective.GrossActual)/Sum(tObjective.CommitGrossObj) as CommitGross,
 Sum(tObjective.ActualMTD)/Sum(tObjective.GrossActual) AS MTDPRU 
 FROM tObjective, tMake, tDealerships
 WHERE tObjective.DealershipID = 10
 AND NewUsed = 'New'
 AND tObjective.MakeID = tMake.MakeID
 AND tObjective.DealershipID = tDealerships.DealershipID
 AND (tMake.Make LIKE '%BUICK%'
 OR tMake.Make LIKE '%GMC%')
 GROUP BY tMake.Make, tDealerships.CapShortName
```

Comment: Close, instead of getting two results, I still need the single result, but with that result I need to display both makes that I'm summing together.. so ideally another column that says make with both Buick/GMC in that column.

Comment: That makes sense now, you may want to clarify that in your question for future users to find this question easier(when it gets solved.